# Show that the extreme points of the unit simplex $\Delta_n$ are the unit vectors $e_1,\ldots ,e_n$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis, analytic-geometry

Show that the extreme points of the unit simplex $\Delta_n$ are the unit vectors $e_1,\ldots ,e_n$.
I want to show that $ext(\Delta_n)=\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$
I've thought that proving $\rightarrow$ this part i would take some $x\in ext(\Delta_n)$ and assume that $x\neq e_i$ for all i but i got stuck.
any hints please?

Comment: Interesting and somewhat funny question. Probably the answer depends also on your definition of $\Delta_n$. If it's defined as the set of vectors having non-zero components which sum up to unity, then taking the canonical basis $\{\pmb{e}_j\}$, for **every** such vector $\pmb{x}$ we have by definition or construction that $\pmb{x}=\sum_i x_i \pmb{e}_i$ with $x_1 \ge 0$ and $\sum_i x_i=1$. Thus every vector in $\Delta_n$ can be written as a convex combination of the $\{\pmb{e}_j\}$. These must therefore be the extreme points, since there are $n$ of them and $\Delta_n$ is $(n-1)$-dimensional.

Comment: ...which actually also shows that $\Delta_n$ is specifically a simplex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So take some vector $x=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_je_j\in \Delta_n$ such that $x\not \in \{e_1,...,e_n\}$. Then, there exists $j_0$ such that $\alpha_{j_0}\in (0,1)$. Define $y=\frac{1}{\sum_{j\neq j_o}\alpha_j}(x-\alpha_{j_0} e_{j_0})$. Then, $y$ is well-defined since $\sum_{j\neq j_0} \alpha_j=1-\alpha_{j_0}\neq 0$ and $y\neq x$, since $\alpha_{j_0}\neq 0$. I'll leave it to you to check that $y$, indeed, lies in the simplex.

Furthermore,

$$
x= \alpha_{j_0} e_{j_0}+(1-\alpha_{j_0})y,
$$
so $x$ is not an extreme point.

Now, let $1\leq i \leq n$ and assume that $e_i=tx+(1-t)y$ for some $x=\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j e_j,y=\sum_{j=1}^n \beta_j e_j\in \Delta_n$. Then, projecting on the $i$'th coordinate, we get that $1=t\alpha_i+(1-t) \beta_i$. But since $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are positive and smaller than $1$, this implies $\alpha_i=\beta_i=1$. Now, we simply observe that $\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j=\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_j=1,$ to get that $\alpha_j=\beta_j=0$ for all $j\neq i$. Thus, $x=y=e_i$. In conclusion, the canonical unit vectors are, indeed, extreme points of the $n$-simplex.

Comment: Do you mean that $y=\frac{1}{\sum_{j\neq j_0}\alpha_j}(x-\alpha_{j_0}e_{j_0})$

Comment: Mmm... doesn't "Then, there exists $j_0$ such that $\alpha_{j_0} \in (0,1)$" already assume that the $e_j$ are extreme points?

Comment: No probably not, I see what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, there was a typo in my definition of $y$, thanks. ^^ And no, at no point do I assume that the $e_j$ are the extreme points. The simplex is *defined* as the convex hull of the canonical basis.

Comment: Indeed. The definition leads to a shorter proof: an $(n-1)$-dimensional convex set must have at least $n$ extreme points; and if it has exactly $n$ extreme points, then it's by definition a simplex. Since $\Delta_n$ is defined as the convex hull of $\{e_j\}$, then $\mathrm{ext}(\Delta_n) \subseteq  \{e_j\}$. Given also that $\mathrm{card}[\mathrm{ext}(\Delta_n)] \ge n$ and $\mathrm{card}(\{e_j\})=n$, we have $\mathrm{ext}(\Delta_n) = \{e_j\}$ and, moreover, $\Delta_n$ is a simplex.

Comment: @pglpm It's only a shorter proof if you a) already know that the $n$ simplex is an $(n-1)$-dimensional convex set and b) that the result you quote is true. I generally prefer proofs that are as elementary as possible (obviously, given that they don't become humongous tomes that essentially need to contain a proof of the more advanced results).